# mail/mailx: How to specify recipents with full names?

Tags: email, mailx, mail-command

Rich email clients allow users to be identified likewise:

```
John Smith <jsmith@example.com>
```

How can I use such format for recipients (or other email fields for that matter) with mail and/or mailx?  I want to include the full name in the outgoing email.